Proof that $a^2+b^2 > 2ab$
I'm going through Cunningham's A Logical Introduction to Proof. An exercise is asking to prove that $a^2+b^2 > 2ab$, by letting $a$ and $b$ be distinct numbers and using the fact $x^2 >0$
I understand $a^2+b^2 > 2ab$ is related to the extended form of $(a-b)^2$, but using something like $a^2+b^2 - 2ab > 0$ to start my proof feels like going back to what I'm being asked to prove.
What I know so far tells me that I can take $a^2 > 0$, but if I wanted to get $a^2 + b^2$, wouldn't that turn my inequality in $a^2 + b^2 > b^2$ (by the law that states $a+c < b+c$)? Where does the $2ab$ derives from and how can I even start the proof?

You're making it harder than it is.  $(a-b)^2 \geq 0$.  And thus...?

$a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b)^2>0$ for $a\neq b$. For a different solution, see this post.

You don't know $a\neq0,$ so you can't say $a^2>0.$ You do know $a-b\neq0,$ however.

"...feels like going back to what I'm being asked to prove" : it is not circular reasoning.  Instead, it is perfectly valid.

WARNING: possibly wildly overkill, but I literally don't even care (because I think it will help OP).
Similar to Brian Tung's answer. There is a difference between doing scratch work and writing a logical proof.

Scratch work is stuff you quickly scribble down to see what's going on and get ideas going to try to prove the statement/proposition. Often with scratch work for algebraic proofs like the one here, we start with the statement we are trying to prove and try to end up at a familiar true statement. Note that this does not give us a formal proof, however, since in a formal proof, we cannot start by assuming the thing we are trying to prove is true (as that's cheating!).
However, before we even do scratch work, we need to be crystal clear of the precise statement we are trying to prove.

Statement we are trying to prove (A.K.A. "Proposition"): If $a\neq b,$ then $a^2+b^2 > 2ab.$


Scratch work:
$$a^2 +b^2 > 2ab$$
$$+(-2ab) \text{ to both sides: }\quad  a^2 + b^2 -2ab > 0  $$
$$ (a-b)^2 > 0.$$
We know that last statement is true, so we have sort of got somewhere, maybe. However, this is not yet a logical proof. It is a bunch of (maybe) equivalent statements that haven't yet been joined up in a logical argument (which is all that a proof is at the end of the day). In our proof proper, we have to start with facts we know to be true end up with "Therefore it is true that $a^2 +b^2 > 2ab$ whenever $a\neq b$".

Most people who are new to proofs would do well to write something like the following as a solution:
$$ (a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 -2ab $$
$$ (a-b)^2 \text{ is always } > 0, \text{ therefore } a^2 + b^2 -2ab > 0,$$
$$ \text{ therefore, by adding } 2ab \text{ to both sides, } a^2 + b^2 > 2ab. $$
However, this is not perfect as it is missing details, like working/reasoning of some steps, and it's also missing all-important implication signs or logical indications like "therefore" or "because". Better is:

We are trying to prove that, If $a\neq b,$ then $a^2+b^2 > 2ab.$ So suppose that $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a\neq b.$ [We aim to show that $a^2+b^2 > 2ab.$]
$$ \text{ By expanding brackets, for all } a\in\mathbb{R},\ b\in\mathbb{R},\quad (a-b)^2 = (a-b)(a-b) = a(a-b) -b(a-b)=a^2 -ab -ba+b^2= a^2 + b^2 -2ab. $$
$$ \text{In particular, for all } a\in\mathbb{R},\ b\in\mathbb{R}, \text{ with } a\neq b,\quad (a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 -2ab. $$
$$ \text{ Since } a\neq b,\ \text{ it follows that } a-b\neq 0, \text{ and so either } a-b <0 \text{ or } a-b>0. \text{ Either way, we have: } (a-b)^2=(a-b)(a-b),$$
$$ \text{ which is either two positive numbers multiplied together or two negative numbers multiplied together, and therefore is always } > 0.$$
$$\text{ In summary, } (a-b)^2 >0. \text{ Therefore, } a^2 + b^2 -2ab \text{ is always }> 0.$$
$$ \text{ Therefore, by adding } 2ab \text{ to both sides, } a^2 + b^2 > 2ab. $$

This is overkill, but it's better to be overkill with proofs and then later on reel them in by making them more concise, but only once you are confident that the steps you intend on omitting from the proof are correct.
So you see that formulating algebraic proofs takes several stages.

Clearly state the proposition you wish to prove.
Jot down ideas and scratch work that hopefully sort-of prove the proposition (albeit not in a logical manner, but maybe it would be logical if the order of the steps are reversed).
Try to arrange all your ideas in a logically deductive proof.
Check to make sure your proof is valid and sound, and that you have started with statements you already know to be true like axioms, and then the proof finishes with the proposition being shown to be a true statement.
Keep in mind that proofs are usually a work in progress and can always be improved in clarity and brevity. For example, my Proposition statement itself can be clarified to: "If $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\neq b,$ then $a^2+b^2 > 2ab$", since one might wonder from the proposition I originally wrote if $a$ and $b$ could be allowed to be complex numbers or something else.
As you get better at proofs, sometimes you can omit some of the details, although you should not omit the logical implication part of your proof, because, for example, $A\implies B$ is not the same as $B \implies A.$


You may be experiencing the difference between discovering a proof and articulating it. This is possibly the result of a long-lived movement in mathematics education: the tendency to present results as though they were handed down from on high, without much motivation.
From that perspective, there's no problem, because although it may seem arbitrary to start your proof with "$a \not= b$, therefore $(a-b)^2 > 0$"—for some people, it's not clear why you would know to start with that—it's not actually logically prior to your desired conclusion. You're not assuming that which you want to prove.
However, for those people, it does seem epistemologically prior, in the sense that they don't see how to motivate starting that way. All I can offer in the way of guidance there is that this seems to me mostly a matter of experience: You see those terms, and your mind will eventually more or less immediately leap to that approach. There's no particular short cut to that state of mind, I'm afraid.

Work with equivalence signs:
$a^2+b^2>2ab \Leftrightarrow a^2-2ab+b^2>0 \Leftrightarrow (a-b)^2 > 0 \Leftrightarrow a \neq b$

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $a+bc=2$. Prove that:
$$a+b+c\geq\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}.$$
